# Verify new password with LDAP

Tags: ldap

Does LDAP has some methods for varify new password, i mean not just change old to

new one but check if new password is valid

For example, I need to notify user before he will change password - valid or not it

will be. I face with this problem cause usually LDAP has some password policy and I need to find a way to get some message why new password could be invalid

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation that your are using. OpenLDAP can check password policies by means of overlays. A detailed documentation can be found [here](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html).

If you are working in a UNIX environment where LDAP is used for authentication purposes in conjunction with Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM), then you could use a PAM module that enforces the password policies. You could have a look at the pam_cracklib module. If this module does not exactly what you want, it is not too difficult to write your own module that can check the structure of a given password (e.g. against a regular expression) if you have some knowledge in C.

Best wishes and regards,
  Julian

Comment: Thanks. I am using Microsoft Active Directory. So I need to write my own implementation or try to find out, maybe AD already has such functionality. Good to know maybe somebody face with that problem too